# Liferay: how do I add verication URL to new account e-mail

Tags: liferay-6

(Using Liferay 6.1.0-CE-GA1.) I have written my own user registration portlet. When I UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser(...), the sendEmail parameter is true and, indeed, it sends the Account Verification Notification.

I've modified that notification by adding this line to it:

```
Please verify your email address for [$PORTAL_URL$] by clicking this link: [$EMAIL_VERIFICATION_URL$].
```

Unfortunately the e-mail it sends contains this line, literally:

> Please verify your email address for xxx by clicking this link: [$EMAIL_VERIFICATION_URL$].

Is there any way to make this work? I want to send one e-mail with the verification code. My program flow requires it.

Thank you.

Comment: I've also tried the following immediately after creating the Liferay user: UserLocalServiceUtil.sendEmailAddressVerification(newUser, email, serviceContext); using the same (rather empty) serviceContext I passed into UserLocalServiceUtil.addUser(). However, this results in an exception from UserLocalServiceUtil containing this message: Error in UserLocalServiceUtil.sendEmailAddressVerification: No Layout exists with the primary key 0. Is there any way to fake this out so it will work? Why does it need a Layout (assuming the Layout it's talking about is a real Layout)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this after you added the account in the action

```
    ServiceContext serv = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(request);
UserLocalServiceUtil.sendEmailAddressVerification(user1, user1.getEmailAddress(), serv);
```

Comment: how can i get     `ServiceContext` without     `request`   
@BabeshFlorin